# Как сделать "Form Submission" в lxml?

Tags: python, парсер, lxml

На примере [kinopoisk.ru](http://www.kinopoisk.ru) - хочу в поле поиска засунуть свой текст, и получить страницу с результатами.

```
from lxml.html import parse, submit_form, tostring

page = parse('http://www.kinopoisk.ru/').getroot()
page.forms[0].fields['kp_query'] = 'Youth, 2015'
result = parse(submit_form(page.forms[0])).getroot()
print(tostring(result, encoding='unicode'))
```

[Документацию](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#forms) прочитал. Возможно проблема в том, что не могу понять, каким образом определяется значение page.forms[?]. Это порядковый номер поля? Если проблема в номере, тогда как узнать, какой номер поля поиска у кинопоиска?

Пробовал разные цифры - если не 0, то выдает `KeyError: "No input element with the name 'kp_query'"`

Что делаю не так?

Comment: У Вас вопрос не как форму отправить, а как найти элемент формы на странице -- что делается также как и для любого другого html элемента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно по `id` найти форму:

```
form = page.cssselect('#top_form')[0]
```

`submit_form(form, open_http=open_http)` отправит форму и вернёт результат (что `open_http()` хук возвращает -- по умолчанию результат `urlopen()`), но нет гарантии что это желаемый результат, если сайт использует javascript для генерации формы/её отправки или использует какие-либо меры по защите от ботов.

---

Если необходимо изменить как http-запросы делаются, то достаточно `open_http()` свой передать в `submit_form()`, например, в данном случае:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlsplit, urlunsplit

def open_http(method, URL, values): # method == 'GET' in this case
    return opener.open(urlunsplit(('http', 'kinopoisk.ru', 
                       urlsplit(URL).path, urlencode(values), '')))
```

где `opener` -- это стандартный `opener` из `urllib.request`, например, можно сделать, чтобы запросы шли через tor-сервис со случайным `User-Agent` http заголовком и другими настройками по желанию:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
import fake_useragent # $ pip install fake-useragent
import socks  # $ pip install PySocks
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler  # from pysocks

socks_port = 9050 # tor socks5 port
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "localhost", socks_port))
opener.addheaders = [
    ('User-Agent', fake_useragent.UserAgent().random,
    ('Accept-Language', 'ru;q=0.8, en;q=0.7')
]
```

Можно `open_http()` не переопределять, а просто вызывать `urllib2.install_opener(opener)`, чтобы во всём процессе автоматически этот `opener` использовать.

Answer (score 0):

С lxml в данном случае в лоб не получится - сайт требует User-agent.
Или делать через [Grab](http://grablib.org/) (он использует во всех запросах User-agent-а)

```
from grab import Grab

g = Grab()
g.go('http://www.kinopoisk.ru/')
g.doc.set_input('kp_query', 'Youth, 2015')
g.doc.submit()
print(g.doc.select('//*').html())
```

либо через requests или urllib